# Accessing Cache Slower than Accessing Database

Tags: mysql, redis, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I am tinkering with redis and mysql to see how caching can improve performance. Accesing data from Cache is/should be faster than accessing it from database.

I calculated the time required for both the case in my program and found out that **accesing from cache was much slower than accesing from the database** . I was/am wondering what might be the cause(s).

Some points to consider:

1. I am using Azure Redis Cache.
2. The main application is on VM instance.
3. I hosted MYSQL server on another VM instance.
4. The table is very small with 200-300 records.
5. There is no error in the time calculation logic.

EDIT:

Load time for cache=about 1.2s

Load time for mysql= about 15ms

Turns out my application and MySQL server were in a same region while the redis cache was in a different region across the globe causing much higher latency.

**But I would still want someone to explain why the fetch time for sql was much more smaller.**

Comment: This is one of many cases where MySQL is so efficient that putting a cache in front of it may not help.  With a "very small" table, there is likely to be no I/O, etc.  How many milliseconds are you seeing for each case?

Comment: about 1.2s for cache and about 15ms for database  and i am wondering why is fetching from mysql this fast

Answer (score 0):

If the table of 200-300 rows is fully cached in MySQL's "buffer_pool", then it won't take much time to fetch all of them and send them back to the client.  15ms is reasonable (though it depends on too many things to be more specific).

If you are fetching 1 row, and you have an index (esp, the PRIMARY KEY) to locate that one row, I would expect it to be even faster than 15ms.

I'm summarizing a 40K-row table; it is taking under 2ms.  But note: client and server are on the same machine.  15ms could represent the client and server being a few hundred miles apart.

How long does a simple `SELECT 1` take?  That will give you a clue of the latency, below which you cannot go without changing the physical location of machines.